# Inefficient Azure mobile apps query consuming lots of Azure SQL DTUs

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have an application that uses the Azure Mobile Apps .NET backend and Windows Client.  One of the tables being synced between the backend and client has 30,000 rows.   When syncing this table, the DTU spikes to around 60% of my 100 DTU (S3) tier, which is very bad.   The monitoring graph looks like this:

[image]

The table controller for this table is pretty basic:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<MyBigTable>> GetMyBigTable()
{
   return Query();
}
```

The following is the SQL generated by Azure Mobile Apps:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (51) 
[Project2].[Field1] AS [Field1], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project2].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Project2].[C3] AS [C3],
...
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    ...
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
        ...
        FROM [dbo].[MyBigTable] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[UpdatedAt] >= @p__linq__0)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[UpdatedAt] ASC, [Project1].[Id] ASC
    OFFSET @p__linq__1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @p__linq__2 ROWS ONLY 
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[UpdatedAt] ASC, [Project2].[Id] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 datetimeoffset(7),@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__2 int',@p__linq__0='2017-02-28 03:48:49.4840000 +00:00',@p__linq__1=0,@p__linq__2=50
```

... not very pretty, and far too complicated for its ultimate purpose, but that's another matter.   The problem, I think, which explains the shape of the graph, is that the inner SQL aliased as `[Project1]` *always* returns all rows from `[UpdatedAt]` till the end of the table.   **This inner SQL would have been the ideal place to put a TOP 51 clause, but instead it's found in the outer SQLs**.

So, although each paging call from the client returns only 50 rows to the client, the first call causes the *inner SQL* to return all rows; the next call, 50 rows less than the previous, and so on.  This, I think, explains the shape of the graph.

Is there any way to influence how the SQL is generated, or even override the SQL with my own?   Does this mean that I need to extract the OData query?  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The SQL is generated by Entity Framework, so there is little we can do about the form of the SQL, short of writing a non-EF domain manager.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHall, I feared as much.   This isn't the first time I encountered severe performance issues with EF in this application.   It's too bloated and opaque.   I used Dapper in other parts where I could, and I wished I could use it everywhere instead of EF.   Perhaps a future version of Mobile Apps will let you swap in your own ORM?    But this won't solve my problem now.   Some advice on a possible way forward would be appreciated.

Comment: The current version of Azure Mobile Apps lets you swap in your own ORM - you just have to write the domain manager for it (which is an implementation of IDomainManager) to replace the EntityDomainManager that the team provides.